instagram profile_picture_url Bad URL hash
I authorized with instagram .after that I get user profile and graph API response me  : "profile_picture_url" -> "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/463428552_1674211683359002_2290477567584105157_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s206x206&_nc_ca…"
.So when I access link it response Bad URL Hash..Every one can help me??
